# Change CheckedListBox ItemsSource

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I'm trying to change dynamically the items source inside a CheckedListBox and also keep their selected values?

```
 CheckedListBox1 |   CheckedListBox2
[x] list0        |   [ ] list0item0
[ ] list1        |   [ ] list0item1
[ ] list2        |   [ ] list0item2
[ ] list3        |   [ ] list0item3
```

and when list1 is selected (not CHECKED, just highligted) update the CheckedListBox2 items

```
 CheckedListBox1 |   CheckedListBox2
[ ] list0        |   [ ] list1item0
[x] list1        |   [ ] list1item1
[ ] list2        |   [ ] list1item2
[ ] list3        |   [ ] list1item3
```

here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fizPm.png) that describes my question.

here is a code snippet:

```
    public void customModuleFunctionsCheckedListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //checks before calling this function if there is any element selected..
                for (int i = 0; i < this.mainForm.customFunctionList[index].Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (this.mainForm.customFunctionList[index].SelectedIndex == i)
                    {
                        this.mainForm.customFunctionUseCasesList[index].Items.Clear();
//this.mainForm.customFunctionUseCasesList[index].ItemsSourceOrWhateverMethodIs = aListOfStrings....

                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there any clean solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to my own question might be this.
But i need to place strings instead of (collection) inside of CheckedListBox1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<List<object>> function;
        List<object> useCase;

        public Form1()
        {
            function = new List<List<object>>();
            useCase =new List<object>();

            InitializeComponent();


            useCase.AddRange(new object[] {
            "List0Item0",
            "List0Item1",
            "List0Item2",
            "List0Item3",
            "List0Item4",
            "List0Item5"});

            this.function.Add(this.useCase);

            this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add(function);

            useCase = new List<object>();
            useCase.AddRange(new object[] {
            "List1Item0",
            "List1Item1",
            "List1Item2",
            "List1Item3",
            "List1Item4",
            "List1Item5"});

            this.function.Add(this.useCase);

            this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add(function);


        }

        private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.checkedListBox2.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.function.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex == i)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < this.function[i].Count(); j++)
                    {
                        this.checkedListBox2.Items.Add(this.function[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

output of the code attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev1X1.png).

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert at c#, much more like a newbie !
But I thought of this in this way.
When someone selects a value from the listBox1(on Click) it cleans the listBox2 results and the query that was done by default or the previous query.
And after the listBox1 item is selected the listBox2 onClick is going to do a query based on listBox1 item choosen.

```
if(listBox1.Selecteditem == "Fruit")
{
  query to database WHERE item is Fruit
}
```

I can't be able to confirm though but i found some documentation on this sort of listbox selected things.

[Microsoft ListBox Selected items documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Hope this helps ! :)

Comment: sorry reread my question. I accidentaly said listbox instead of checkedlistbox :") sorry!!